# Python: open tab in MacVim or gvim

Tags: python, vim

I'm writing an application which opens one or more files in the GUI vim text editor. The different files will be handled by threads. Now, when I open the second file, the thread opens MacVim a second time (which causes it to hang also) but what I actually want is that it opens a second tab. This is how far I got:

```
import threading
import os
from subprocess import call

EDITOR = os.environ.get("EDITOR", "/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim")

class MyThread (threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, sf):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sf = sf

    def run (self):
        call([EDITOR, self.sf])

L = ["/path/to/file1.txt", 
 "/path/to/file2.txt"]

while True:

    path_to_file = L.pop()
    tr = MyThread(path_to_file) 
    tr.start()

    answer = input("Another thread to start? ")
    if answer is not 'y':
        break
```

---

EDIT AFTER FINDING THE SOLUTION (based on the answer given below):

```
 def run (self):
    call([EDITOR, "--remote-tab-silent", self.sf])
```

There doesn't seem to be a need to create the server explicitly since there is a default server called VIM. So by giving the option `--remote-tab-silent` it starts using it right away.

Comment: "So by giving the option `--remote-tab-silent` it starts using it right away." - awesome. :) Just one small warning that you probably already thought of: if the user has `EDITOR` set to something non-Vim (such as `kate` or `emacs`), it will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:help client-server
```

Don't open multiple Vims. Open one Vim, make it a server, then send commands to it to open additional tabs. This way, you don't need threading (unless your threads are also doing something else), since each vim invocation will resolve instantaneously, just sending a command to the running server, and then exiting (as long as there is a server that is already running).

Comment: It seems that vim doesn't ship with the server option compiled in. Since I want this to run on any standard environment where the user s not supposed to compile vim, I can't really make use of it, is that correct?

Comment: Not sure. My MacVim has it compiled in; I would suspect gVim would as well, but can't check. Plain default Vim probably does not, but it doesn't have tabs, either.

Comment: How can I check this for MacVim? When I do  ./MacVim –servername SAMPLESERVER file1.txt it opens 3 windows (-servername, SAMPLESERVER and file1.txt) for 3 new files.

Comment: `:echo has("clientserver")` - it should return `1`. Or you can do `:version` and see that it has `+clientserver`.

Comment: Nice, it does have it compiled in. But I can't start it up. Why doesn't it accept the above command?

Comment: I believe you have a single dash in `-servername`; double dash is required for long options (`--servername`).